# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: android, crash

I am new in Android Studio and I just started my first app.
my app is crashing from an unknown reason, hope you will help me to fix it

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ronz2.myfirstapp, PID: 3096
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
    at com.example.ronz2.myfirstapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:21)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is the MainActivity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText firstNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
            EditText secondNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);
            TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

           int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumEditText.getText().toString());
           int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumEditText.getText().toString());
           int result = num1 + num2;

           resultTextView.setText(result + "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Add your MainActivity code here, So that I can help easily?

Comment: share some code

Comment: This is the clue `ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`.

Comment: Post your activity's xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** this is the only relevant code then one of these ids: `firstNumEditText` or `secondNumEditText` does not belong to an `EditText` but to a `ConstraintLayout`. 

So one of these lines:

```
EditText firstNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
EditText secondNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);
```

throws the exception, because you are trying to cast a `ConstraintLayout` to an `EditText`. 
 
Check any `ConstraintLayout`'s id in your xml that matches with these 2 ids and change it.